# What is the rightway to logout user in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Currently I have a logout button and logout button redirects user to a logout component!
I want to know if this is a correct way to logout a user?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { logout } from "../../actions/authActions";

class LogOut extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.logout();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    logout: () => {
      dispatch(logout());
    },
  };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LogOut);
```

Update :  I am using jwt and I want to basically do two tasks that is redirect the user to home page and also clear the jwt token (for which I am dispatching logout action)

Comment: Hi, why you need to redirect the user to a page instead of simply call logout actions inside the onClick function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand your question correctly the right way to logout would depend on what is the method you are logging in with.

Ex: If its was the JWT method the way to  logout is to basically to delete or remove the JWT token.

Comment: Yes I am using jwt and I want to basically do two tasks that is redirect the user to home page and also clear the jwt token (for which I am dispatching logout action)

Comment: Lets talk about clearing the token, depends on where are you keeping it. If its on the redux store just replace the token variable to an empty string or change it to `undefined`. The the redirect you can use routes or have a reducer do it.